# trying to get 1 element of each kind using Laravel Sql query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So i've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and here I come asking my first question on StackOverflow

I am trying to get 1 element of each plantBase_id

```
id / user_id / plantBase_id
1 / 1 / 2
2 / 1 / 2
3 / 1 / 2
4 / 1 / 5
5 / 1 / 5
```

[database + query image]

[image: 1]

I would like it to return this :

```
id / user_id / plantBase_id
1 / 1 / 2
4 / 1 / 5
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way using `window function`:

```
select * from
 (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by plantBase_id order by id) rn
  from tablename
 ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I think I just found a solution to my problem! 
using : 

$recoltes = Recolte::select()->distinct('plantBase_id')->groupBy('plantBase_id')->get();

Comment: thank you for yout time tho! Appreciate it